# Why is @Required set for setters and not fields?

Tags: java, spring, setter, required

If I have the following class:

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Required;

public class Customer 
{
    private Person person;

    public Person getPerson() {
        return person;
    }
    @Required
    public void setPerson(Person person) {
        this.person = person;
    }
}
```

Why in Spring is the @Required tag tied to the setter, and not the field, like this?

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Required;

public class Customer 
{
    @Required
    private Person person;

    public Person getPerson() {
        return person;
    }
    public void setPerson(Person person) {
        this.person = person;
    }
}
```

The dependency is that the property is set, but doesn't need to be tied down to one specific setter that populates that property or field, unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traditionally a bean had properties defined as a getter and/or setter. The private field can be left out (sometimes name "virtual" field). In the new Java EE standard beans are more loose, and might also have a property defined as public field.

Nevertheless Spring pre-dates the latest standard, and having the annotation on a method i.o. a field has the advantage that access can be intercepted via AOP (simple byte code manipulation).

Comment: Field accesses can be intercepted by AOP too (witness AspectJ) but they require a substantial rewrite of the class instead of simpler things like method overriding (Spring AOP with CGLIB) or proxies (Spring AOP _without_ CGLIB).

Comment: @DonalFellows I was aware of the effort taken by AspectJ; therefore my "simple". But maybe the Spring pre-dates that.

Comment: I don't know which preceded which, but I believe that they were initially independent efforts that grew together later.

Comment: I think the point is, though, that other annotations that Spring recognises can be applied to the field (e.g. `@Autowired`, `@Resource`, and so on), so why not @Required too?

Comment: @Jules a valid point: but do you not think that implementing `@Required` is less feasible (intercepting setting a field) than for a setter? `@Autowired` needs just a bit of java reflection.